# Difference in local & let scoping rule?

Tags: julia

In the following example:

```
Fs = cell(2)
i = 1
for i = 1:2
    local i # same as local i = i
    Fs[i] = () -> i
end
println(Fs[1]()) # 1
println(Fs[2]()) # 2
println(i) # 1
```

1. Is it true that `local i` is the same as `local i = i`?
2. Why cannot I do the same for `while` loop as such?

   ```
   Fs = cell(2)
   i = 1
   while i <= 2  #LoadError: UndefVarError: i not define
       local i = i
       Fs[i] = ()->i
       i += 1
   end
   ```

But have to use `let`:

```
Fs = cell(2)
i = 1
while i <= 2
    let i = i
        Fs[i] = ()->i
    end
    i += 1
end
println(Fs[1]()) # 1
println(Fs[2]()) # 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you introduce new variable, and try to get it's value before assignment, Julia throws an `UndefVarError` error, in the first example:

```
Fs = cell(2)
i = 1
for i = 1:2
    local i # same as local i = i
    Fs[i] = () -> i
end
println(Fs[1]()) # 1
println(Fs[2]()) # 2
println(i) # 1
```

For block introduces a new local `i`, adn for command itself assign it so the code successfully dose it's duty. But in the second example:

```
Fs = cell(2)
i = 1
while i <= 2  #LoadError: UndefVarError: i not define
    local i = i
    Fs[i] = ()->i
    i += 1
end
```

A new `i` was introduced in `while` block, but before assignment you try to get it's value, and this produces an error.

In 3d one `let` command declare a **new** local block and a new `i` variable for it's block.

```
julia> function test3()
         Fs = cell(2)
         i = 1
         while i <= 2
             let i = 100
               println(i)
             end
             i += 1
         end
         println(i)
       end
test3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test3()
100
100
3# while block use the function's scope
```